# Deleting rows in table Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I'm printing table using function:

```
   function findL(val){
var i;
//alert(splitted + " " + JSDate);
for(i=0;i<jsData.length; i++)
    {
        if(jsData[i].get_date() == val)
            {

                $('<tr>').append($('<td>').html(jsData[i].get_startT))
                .append($('<td>').html(jsData[i].get_endT))
                .append($('<td>').html(jsData[i].get_prow))
                .append($('<td>').html(jsData[i].get_przedm))
                .append($('<td>').html(jsData[i].get_sala))
                .appendTo('#pzTbody');

            }
        }}
```

As an argument function takes date from datepicker, and when I pick another date it adds to the previously viewed rows.
My problem is that I tried plenty ways to cleaning/deleting old rows before next search.

I tried `deleteRow()`, `.parentNode` in loop etc. Anyone know how to delete appended rows?

Comment: What is it that identifies the rows to be deleted?

Comment: `$("tr").remove()` finds all rows and then removes them, you can make the selector more specific yourself

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I thought about function clean(tbody) that delete whole table body

Comment: You need to rephrase your problem.

Comment: @fegemo what's wrong with it that I need to rephrased?

Comment: What is this search you talk about? Which rows do you want to delete? Old rows? What is old in this case?

Comment: this whole function findL is searching data from an Array. I want to delete all rows that have been appended during previous use of this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code I assuem `pzTbody` is the id of your table. To clean the table body and remove all rows do this:

```
$("#pzTbody").empty();
```

If you just want to remove the last row, use this:

```
$("#pzTbody tr:last-child").remove();
```

Comment: Works the way that I wanted to. Thank you very much for help :)